# Meaning of <<< and >>> in x86 disassembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I can't seem to understand what the `>>>` and the `<<<` characters seem to in x86 disassembly

For example:

```
CMP        BYTE PTR [EAX+33H],0
JE         -126CB479H >>> +33
```

or

```
LEA        ESI,DWORD PTR [ECX+0CH]  <<< +19
```

I understand the basic instruction here; `Jump when Equal` which appears after the `Compare` and the `Load Effective Address` but the `>>>` and `<<<` are confusing me. Any guidance will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Details missing: where did you see this? Is it assembly or disassembly? What tool, if any, accepts this as an input format?

Comment: Sorry, this from a disassembled method. I'm not sure of the tools that accept this. This is something I came across when preparing for a test.

Comment: It seems like a disassembly with just comments, and it could be for example kind of debugging info, say in the JE -126CB479H >>> +33 ">>> +33" means that it jumps in result +33. Or LEA ESI,DWORD PTR [ECX+0CH] <<< +19 looks like the ECX was known at this place, and totally it is loading +19 (in Dec) which is ECX + 0C (in Hex)

Comment: These are annotations which are not part of the machine code. What does your disassembler's documentation say? I concur with Ruslan; my hypothesis is identical to his.

Answer (score 5):

They're indicators of jump destinations.   It's a simplistic form of IDA Pro's output, similar to many clones.

```
CMP        BYTE PTR [EAX+33H],0
JE         -126CB479H >>> +33
```

This indicates that the destination of the `JE` command is +33 bytes further down (>>> going somewhere...)

```
LEA        ESI,DWORD PTR [ECX+0CH]  <<< +19
```

This indicates that this instruction is the destination (<<< - coming from) of a jump/branch/call which is +19 bytes further down.  19 bytes later, 19 bytes higher in memory... you get the idea...

They are *not* part of any standard assembly language, personally, those indicators should be used with a comment delimiter.  Example:

```
CMP        BYTE PTR [EAX+33H],0
JE         -126CB479H               ; >>> +33
LEA        ESI,DWORD PTR [ECX+0CH]  ; <<< +19
```

Pretend you're drawing lines showing logic flow...

```
CMP        BYTE PTR [EAX+33H],0
JE         -126CB479H               ; >>> +33 ---+
                                                 |
; many wonderful and varied instructions here    |
                                                 |
HLT                                 ; <<< -33 ---+
```

Does this help?

Comment: That `-126CB479H` is just _ugly_!   It's not negative since its value is less than 7FFFFFFFH, but it's hex... grrr!   Negative decimal values are fine, like `-2` which is `FFFFFFFEH` in 32bit int's.  Now I'm going to have nightmares! (I prefer the 0x prefix as hex indicator too)

Comment: Presumably it *was* greater than 7FFFFFFF, and the 126CB479 is two's-complement

Comment: {Grin}  It still feels wrong!  OP said came from a test... perhaps a randomly generated value.  I'm just grumbling in jest, the combination of hex and negatives is odd in my experience.